# Checking for digits in an input with isNumeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if there is at least 1 digit in an input field. If there is I want to change the default image.

I am getting an error with the `.isNumeric` function. I know in the docs it shows `$.isNumeric`, but I am not sure how to add that within `hasNumber.isNumeric().length >= 1;`.

I am open to a different function if it will allow this to work.

```js
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var hasNumber = $("#password").val();
  var hasNumberValid = hasNumber.isNumeric().length >= 1;
  $('#upperCase').attr('src', hasNumberValid ? 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlyqJ14HYP1WclpK9RkJWo8jIDBkhTW0GS31AxRkozAEA72ULhY89LIzk' : 'icons/collection/delete.png');
});
```

```css
#password-check {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.password-check-field {
  color: black;
}
.password-check-field img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="password-check-field">
    <img id="upperCase" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">Your password has at a number in it
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try `$.isNumeric(hasNumber)`

Comment: `var isNumeric = $.isNumeric(value_to_check);`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/ . try `$.isNumeric(hasNumber)`

Comment: "I know in the docs it shows `$.isNumeric`"... so use that?

Comment: Or regex: `var patt = new RegExp("[0-9]"); var hasNumberValid = patt.test(hasNumber);`

Comment: @j08691 Thanks. That did the trick! Feel free to leave an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$.isNumeric()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/) accepts an argument of any value, so you can pass in your `$("#password").val()` to it via:

`$.isNumeric(hasNumber)` or `$.isNumeric( $("#password").val() )`

> The `$.isNumeric()` method checks whether its argument represents a
>   numeric value. If so, it returns `true`. Otherwise it returns `false`. The
>   argument can be of any type.

No need to use `length` on that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```js
$('#register').keyup(function() {
  var hasNumber = $("#password").val();
  var hasNumberValid = false;
  
  var inputArray = hasNumber.split('');
  
  inputArray.forEach(function(element) {
    if($.isNumeric(element))
      {
         hasNumberValid = true
       }
   });
  

  $('#upperCase').attr('src', hasNumberValid ? 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQlyqJ14HYP1WclpK9RkJWo8jIDBkhTW0GS31AxRkozAEA72ULhY89LIzk' : 'icons/collection/delete.png');
});
```

```css
#password-check {
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.password-check-field {
  color: black;
}
.password-check-field img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="register">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" required>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Choose a password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="password-check-field">
    <img id="upperCase" src="icons/collection/delete.png" alt="Success">Your password has at a number in it
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`isNumeric()` returns a boolean. Check to see if it's true. Try using [$.isNumeric()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

```
var hasNumberValid = $.isNumeric(hasNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex in order to check if there is a number in your string

```
var hasNumberValid = hasNumber.match(/\d+/g) != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the keyup on your password field instead of the form and use a regular expression instead of isNumericn since the documentation states that "Description: Determines whether its argument represents a JavaScript number." I'm not sure whether it will be true in the case where you have both numbers and letters.

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/k4yc45jo/)

```
var AtLestOneLetterAndOneNumberRegex = new RegExp(".*[0-9].*");
$('#password').keyup(function() {
  var passwordValue = $("#password").val();
  if (AtLestOneLetterAndOneNumberRegex.test(passwordValue)){

    $("#validPasswordMessage").css("visibility","visible");
  }

});
```

Comment: I did not rename the long variable, I apologize, this is only checking for one number it's not checking for letters